# Is it Ok that creating TensorFlow device multiple times

Tags: tensorflow

I've run a image processing script using tensorflow API. It turns out that the processing time decreased quickly when I set the for-loop outside the session running procedure. Could anyone tell me why? Is there any side-effects?

The original code:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
for i in range(len(file_list)):
    start = time.time()
    image_crop, bboxs_crop = sess.run(crop_image(file_list[i], bboxs_list[i], sess))
    print( 'Done image %d th in %d ms \n'% (i, ((time.time() - start)*1000)))
    # image_crop, bboxs_crop, image_debug = sess.run(crop_image(file_list[i], bboxs_list[i], sess))
    labels, bboxs = filter_bbox(labels_list[i], bboxs_crop)
    # Image._show(Image.fromarray(np.asarray(image_crop)))
    # Image._show(Image.fromarray(np.asarray(image_debug)))
    save_image(image_crop, ntpath.basename(file_list[i]))
    #save_desc_file(file_list[i], labels_list[i], bboxs_crop)
    save_desc_file(file_list[i], labels, bboxs)
coord.request_stop()
coord.join(threads)
```

The code modified:

```
for i in range(len(file_list)):
with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    start = time.time()
    image_crop, bboxs_crop = sess.run(crop_image(file_list[i], bboxs_list[i], sess))
    print( 'Done image %d th in %d ms \n'% (i, ((time.time() - start)*1000)))
    labels, bboxs = filter_bbox(labels_list[i], bboxs_crop)
    save_image(image_crop, ntpath.basename(file_list[i]))
    save_desc_file(file_list[i], labels, bboxs)
```

The time cost in the original code would keep increasing from 200ms to even 20000ms. While after modified, the the logs messages indicate that there are more than one graph and tensorflow devices were created during running, why is that?

> python random_crop_images_hongyuan.py  I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA
>   library libcublas.so.8.0 locally I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA
>   library libcudnn.so.5 locally I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA
>   library libcufft.so.8.0 locally I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA
>   library libcuda.so.1 locally I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA
>   library libcurand.so.8.0 locally W
>   tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow
>   library wasn't compiled to use SSE3 instructions, but these are
>   available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations. W
>   tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow
>   library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are
>   available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations. W
>   tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow
>   library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are
>   available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations. W
>   tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow
>   library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are
>   available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations. W
>   tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow
>   library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are
>   available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations. W
>   tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow
>   library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are
>   available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations. I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:910] successful
>   NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be
>   at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:885] Found device 0
>   with properties:  name: GeForce GT 730M major: 3 minor: 5
>   memoryClockRate (GHz) 0.758 pciBusID 0000:01:00.0 Total memory:
>   982.88MiB Free memory: 592.44MiB I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:906] DMA: 0  I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:916] 0:   Y  I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating
>   TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GT 730M, pci
>   bus id: 0000:01:00.0) Done image 3000 th in 317 ms
>
> I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating
>   TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GT 730M, pci
>   bus id: 0000:01:00.0) Done image 3001 th in 325 ms
>
> I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating
>   TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GT 730M, pci
>   bus id: 0000:01:00.0) Done image 3002 th in 312 ms
>
> I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating
>   TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GT 730M, pci
>   bus id: 0000:01:00.0) Done image 3003 th in 147 ms
>
> I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating
>   TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GT 730M, pci
>   bus id: 0000:01:00.0) Done image 3004 th in 447 ms

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that this happens because creating the session is an expensive operation. May be it could also happen that the session is not properly cleaned when the with-statement is left, so each new allocation on the device will have less resources available. In short, I would not recommend doing it this way, rather initialize just one session and try to reuse it.

EDIT:
In answer to your comment: The session is closed automatically as soon as the with-block is exited. I've read in [this github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1578) that the memory on the GPU is only really released when the whole program exits. But I guess that when you allocate a new session after you closed the last one, Tensorflow will internally just re-use the previously allocated resources. So, in retrospective my answer is probably not very insightful. Sorry if I caused confusion.

Comment: How to clean resource when the with-statement is left? could you kindly explain this more specific?

Comment: I know session.close could be used when leaving the whole session, while involved with-loop, I'm not sure should session.close be called when each with-statement leaves?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to be 100% certain without seeing all of your code, but I would guess that the `crop_image()` function is calling various TensorFlow op functions to build a graph.

It is almost never a good idea to build a graph inside a `for` loop. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35705890/3574081) explains why: some operations (such as the first `Session.run()` call to a new operation) take time that is linear in the number of operations in the graph. If you add more operations in each iteration, iteration `i` will do work that is linear in `i`, and so the overall execution time will be quadratic.

The modified version of your code (with a `with tf.Graph().as_default():` block inside the loop) will be faster because it creates a new, empty `tf.Graph` in each iteration, and therefore each iteration does a constant amount of work.

An even more efficient solution would be to build the graph and session once, using [`tf.placeholder()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder) tensors to represent the filename and bbox arguments to `crop_image`, and feeding different values to these placeholders in each iteration.