# Session graph is empty

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have been trying to iterate the tensorflow model using the answer provided on 
[Tensorflow : Memory leak even while closing Session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35695183/tensorflow-memory-leak-even-while-closing-session)
I have the same error as mentioned in one of the comments i.e. "The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the graph before calling run()." I cannot figure out how to solve it.

Comment: What is the code you're trying to run?

Answer (score 13):

My suggestion is to make sure your session knows which graph it is running on.
Somethings you can try are:

1. build the graph first and pass in the graph to a session.

   ```
   myGraph = tf.Graph()
   with myGraph.as_default():
       # build your graph here

   mySession = tf.Session(graph=myGraph)
   mySession.run(...)

   # Or

   with tf.Session(graph=myGraph) as mySession:
       mySession.run(...)
   ```
2. If you want to use multiple `with` statement, use it in a nested way.

   ```
   with tf.Graph().as_default():
       # build your graph here
       with tf.Session() as mySession:
           mySession.run(...)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If you search the TensorFlow source code you will find this exclusive message is telling you *the graph version* is 0, which means it is empty.

[image]
You need to [load](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model) the graph from file or to create a graph like this (just an example):

```
import tensorflow as tf

pi = tf.constant(3.14, name="pi")
r = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name="r")
a = pi * r * r

graph = tf.get_default_graph()
print(graph.get_operations())
```

The line `print(graph.get_operations())` will confirm the graph is not empty:

```
[<tf.Operation 'pi' type=Const>, <tf.Operation 'r' type=Placeholder>, <tf.Operation 'mul' type=Mul>, <tf.Operation 'mul_1' type=Mul>]
```