# I forgot to close a tf.InteractiveSession, how do I kill any left over processes?

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I am using the new [Google Colaboratory](https://colab.research.google.com), and I ran a block of code repeatedly that utilized a `tf.InteractiveSession` before I realized that `tf.InteractiveSession.close()` was never called. I modified the code and added a `sess.close()`. Now whenever I run the same code block, I get the following warning:

> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py:1645: UserWarning: An interactive session is already active. This can cause out-of-memory errors in some cases. You must explicitly call `InteractiveSession.close()` to release resources held by the other session(s).
>     warnings.warn('An interactive session is already active. This can '

Whoops. How can I release resources held by the previous sessions I spawned? Even after adding the `sess.close()` command, this warning persists. I assume I am only closing the active session at this point. I tried refreshing the page, but no luck.

- Yeah, in case you can't tell I'm not very familiar with the inner workings (including memory management and state persistence) of Jupyter notebooks.

This question is very similar to: [Is it necessary to close session after tensorflow InteractiveSession()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50229091/is-it-necessary-to-close-session-after-tensorflow-interactivesession) but I need to know how to actually close the zombie processes, which isn't covered in this answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13202), you can use

`import gc; gc.collect()`.

Also you can always get the number of active sessions with

`tf.InteractiveSession._active_session_count`